# Gradle Script Kotlin and dependencyManagement

Tags: spring, gradle, kotlin, build-script

I am trying to port Spring Cloud Stream app build script to Kotlin. So far, so good, except the dependency management block. It's difficult to find anything in the net. Samples don't cover that topic, too.

How do I convert following block to `build.gradle.kts`? Thanks.

```
dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:Camden.SR2"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Totally not tested, but I believe it should be something like this:

```
import io.spring.gradle.dependencymanagement.DependencyManagementExtension
import io.spring.gradle.dependencymanagement.ImportsHandler

configure<DependencyManagementExtension> {
    imports(delegateClosureOf<ImportsHandler> {
        mavenBom("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:Camden.SR2")
    })
}
```

If you haven't seen it, you should be familiar with gradle script kotlin's [project extensions](https://github.com/gradle/gradle-script-kotlin/blob/master/src/main/kotlin/org/gradle/script/lang/kotlin/ProjectExtensions.kt) and [groovy interop](https://github.com/gradle/gradle-script-kotlin/blob/master/src/main/kotlin/org/gradle/script/lang/kotlin/GroovyInteroperability.kt) functions. You really have to dig into the source of the groovy plugin you're configuring to see how it expects to use the closure. The examples in the gradle script kotlin project are also a good guide.

***Edit 19 Dec 2016***

The latest version of the dependency management plugin is [now more gradle script kotlin friendly](https://spring.io/blog/2016/12/16/dependency-management-plugin-1-0-0-rc1#better-support-for-gradle-script-kotlin) and will allow the following:

```
configure<DependencyManagementExtension> {
    imports {
        it.mavenBom("io.spring.platform:platform-bom:Camden.SR2")
    }
}
```

It could still benefit from some Kotlin extension functions to remove the need for `it` (using a receiver instead), but definitely an improvement!

***Edit 3 Nov 2017***

It now works without the `it`, like so:

```
configure<DependencyManagementExtension> {
    imports {
        mavenBom("io.spring.platform:platform-bom:Camden.SR2")
    }
}
```

Comment: Works pretty well for an untested solution. Thank you. ;) Unfortunately I am just Kotlin newbie. But thanks for a tip, I'll take a better look into the code.

Comment: No worries. I'm sure the Spring guides/examples will be updated soon when Gradle Script Kotlin is more mature. Though the better solution would be for Spring to provide some extension functions to make the DSL a bit friendlier (no need for `delegateClosureOf()`). e.g. `fun DependencyManagementExtension.imports(imports: DependencyManagementHandler.() -> Unit){ ...}`

Answer (score 9):

Gradle supports importing BOM files in the `dependency` block in both the Groovy and Kotlin DSLs through the `platform` feature. `platform` can be used in a few ways, but you will usually see it used as a way to control the versions of transitive dependencies similar to a dependency with `<scope>import</scope>` in Maven.

The translation of the provided code block would be:

```kotlin
# Kotlin DSL
dependencies {
    // wrap the BOM coordinates with the "platform" keyword
    implementation platform("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:Camden.SR2")

    // declare other dependencies
}
```

Gradle can go a step further to not only suggest the versions of transitive dependencies, but enforce versions as well through `enforcedPlatform`.

```kotlin
dependencies {
   implementation enforcedPlatform("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:Camden.SR2")
}
```

References:
https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management_terminology.html#sub::terminology_platform
https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/platforms.html#sub:bom_import

Answer (score 8):

Using latest `io.spring.dependency-management:1.0.6.RELEASE` below simpler snippet also works.

```
plugins {
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.0.6.RELEASE"
}

dependencyManagement {
    val springCloudVersion = "Finchley.SR2"
    imports {
        mavenBom("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${springCloudVersion}")
    }
}
```